# Windows 7 mklink syntax/privilege error?

Tags: windows-7, mklink

```
C:\Users\Nara\workspaceAndroid>MKLINK /D C:\Develop Folder\Android\NDKDemo C:\Users\Nara\workspaceAndroid
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Any help as to why it's throwing this error. I've already `TAKEOWN` for the Folder yet still when I run the command I see one of the two errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

mklink /d "c:\my path\with spaces\enclosed in\quotes\link" "c:\this one too\if it\has spaces\target"

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the suggestion.